# Set an id for JanusGraph traversal for on-demand transaction trace

Tags: tinkerpop, janusgraph

I want to set a unique identifier for a graph traversal and retrieves it at the JanusGraph storage backend plugin so that I could further trace storage operations related to this graph traversal. My question is that is it possible to do so with the current JanusGraph version and if yes, how?

I am imagining that I could set it similar to this:

```
g.with("traversal_id", "mytraversal").V()....
```

And then retrieve it somehow within the storage manager `beginTransaction`:

```
Transaction tx = db.newTransaction();
String traversalId = ...;  // How to retrieve it here? 
tx.enableTrace(traversalId);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check https://docs.janusgraph.org/advanced-topics/transaction-log/ ?